# Is there anyway to ignore hidden and . git files within a git repository?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am curious if there is anyway to ignore the hidden `/.git` directory as well as other git related files (ie: `.gitignore`) so that I can have a parent git repository that can track the raw local contents of the parent git repository with children git repositories within it.

for example I have a `tree` as follow:

```
C:.
│   .gitignore
│   README.md
│
└───child-repo
        .gitignore
        README.md
```

I do not want the `child-repo` to be a submodule because it will live in a private Azure DevOps instance and submodules are not handled well this way.

I have tried updating the parent `.gitignore` to be:

```
.*
!.gitignore
**/.git
```

As well as adding `.*` to `.git/info/exclue`

and still `child-repo` is treated as a submodule..

Comment: Are you looking to add the contents of the child repo as part of your main repo, or are you wanting to keep it separate?  Also, are you actually storing a repository in the root of your `C:` drive? If so, that's a bad idea.

Comment: >Are you looking to add the contents of the child repo as part of your main repo, or are you wanting to keep it separate? yes as part of the main repo

Comment: @casper Not get your latest information, is VonC's answer helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

`child-repo` should not be treated as a [gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) (not as a submodule, since there is no `.gitmodules` file) if:

- you ignore it
- make sure it is not already tracked

That is:

```
cd /main/repo
git rm --cached child-repo # no trailing slash
echo "child-repo/">>.gitignore
```